# Dataflow returns correct type locally, but not when executed in the cloud

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Given the following table in BigQuery:

[image]

With the following 5 values:

[image]

And a simple ParDo which reads it, and prints the type:

```
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo;

public class FloatBug {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        options.setRunner(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.class);
        options.setProject("<project_id>");
        options.setWorkerMachineType("n1-standard-1");
        options.setZone("us-central1-a");
        options.setStagingLocation("<gcs_bucket>");
        options.setNumWorkers(1);
        options.setMaxNumWorkers(1);
        options.setAutoscalingAlgorithm(DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.AutoscalingAlgorithmType.NONE);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        pipeline.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.from("FLOAT_BUG.float_bug")).apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>() {
            @Override
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                Object o = c.element().get("VHH");
                if (o instanceof Double) {
                    System.out.println("Awesome. Got expected Double: " + o);
                } else if (o instanceof Integer) {
                    System.out.println("Bummer. Got an Integer: " + o);
                } else {
                    assert false;
                }
            }
        }));
        pipeline.run();
    }
}
```

Running locally gives back a Double for **every** value. And that is what I would expect:

```
Awesome. Got expected Double: 2.0
Awesome. Got expected Double: 2.245
Awesome. Got expected Double: 1.773
Awesome. Got expected Double: 4.567
Awesome. Got expected Double: 1.342
```

However, running in the **cloud** using the Dataflow service gives back an `Integer` for the value `2.0`:

```
Awesome. Got expected Double: 2.245
Awesome. Got expected Double: 1.342
Awesome. Got expected Double: 1.773
Awesome. Got expected Double: 4.567
Bummer. Got an Integer: 2
```

It should return a `Double`, not an `Integer` for 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observation is true. A pipeline, which reads input from BigQuery, may output data with a different type than the underlying data type in the BigQuery schema. As observed, the type may also vary from element to element.

This is an unfortunate consequence of the fact that Dataflow Service first exports the data from BigQuery to JSON-encoded files in Google Cloud Storage, and then it reads data from those files. JSON, obviously, doesn't preserve types. For example, a floating point number `2.0` would be encoded as a string `"2"`, which would be read as an `Integer` in Java. This doesn't occur when executing pipelines with `DirectPipelineRunner`, because that runner reads from BigQuery directly.

Now, the easiest way to avoid these kinds of problems is via `Number` abstract class in Java. This is the superclass of classes like `Double` and `Integer`. It should be safe to interpret the result as a `Number` and then call `doubleValue()` method on it.

---

That said, going forward, I expect this behavior to change. The exact timeline is not known yet, but the behavior of the Dataflow Service should shortly match the local execution. A workaround via `Number` class should be correct either way.

Comment: Thanks Davor. Yeah, we already started to change all our code to use Number. But we really shouldn't have to. It should be consistent between the different runners i.e. local & cloud

Comment: I completely agree. You are being exposed to an internal implementation detail here. We'll fix it, just cannot promise the timeline yet.